# save object in module and access it from different modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I am using the following code to parse json data and keep it internally in my module, for example when the server is (like npm server.js) I'm using the function `parse`  which parses the json files.
At the end these parsed jsons are kept in the object `configObj` and I want that during user request's(via express) to get this object in the router module or other modules.

How do I achieve this?

```
var configObj;
parse = function () {
        return fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
            .then(function (res) {
                return JSON.parse(res)
            }).then(function (jsonObj) {
                configObj = jsonObj;
                return jsonObj;
            })
....
        })
    };
    module.exports = {
        parse: parse,
        configObj: configObj
    }
```

The `parse` function is called only once and I want to access to the `configObj` many times in different modules.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, then you could simply `require` that module in every file and node will execute it only the first time and you'll get the cached copy thereafter.

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like [`node-persist`](https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist):

```
var storage = require('node-persist');
storage.setItem('config', configObj);
console.log(storage.getItem('config'));
```

Comment: There is other way to do that except persistence ,since I already read files inside my app folder(the json files)

Comment: Sorry But I dont think that I can use it since they dont provide any license such as MIT etc..

Comment: You can ask the author to release it with a valid license just drop a line here https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist/issues

Answer (score 3):

If you use express best way is `app.set`: when you require your `parse` module function save result for example by:

`app.set("parse.configObj",configObj)`

and get it when need:

`app.get("parse.configObj")`

Or you can use `require.cache` scope after require:

**server.js:**

```
var parse = function () {
        return fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
            .then(function (res) {
                return JSON.parse(res)
            }).then(function (jsonObj) {
                if (typeof require.cache.persist === "undefined") {
                  require.cache.persist = {};
                }
                require.cache.persist.configObj = jsonObj;
                return jsonObj;
            })
    })
};
module.exports = { parse: parse }
```

**app.s**

```
var parse = require('./server.js').parse();
```

**routes/index.js**

```
console.log( require.cache.persist.configObj );
```

Comment: Thanks,1+ can you please provide additional info regard the second option with context of my post,Thanks in advance !

Comment: require.cache['full/path/to/module'].persist = {
    configObj : configObj
} this is confusing ,When to do that and how and how to call it from diffrent module

Comment: Thanks so you are saying that if I put the persist code and I call to the parse object multiple time it will be "cached"?

Comment: and second question until when this cache object is "kept" and this is a common to use this functionality  ?

Comment: Hi any idea regard my questions?